# Matplotlib tick.get_loc() always returns zero

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to get a ticks location to determine if it's too close to the edge of the plot, so that I can remove its label if necessary. However, any method I try always returns zero for the location. Below is some sample code and data which reproduces the issue. How can I get the actual x coordinate of the tick location? PS much of my weird plot formatting is necessary to get the desired result for my end goal plot.

Output:

```
Python: 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
Numpy: 1.11.3
Matplotlib: 2.0.0

0: 0
1: 0
2: 0
3: 0
4: 0
5: 0
```

Code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print('Python: {:}'.format(sys.version))
print('Numpy: {:}'.format(np.__version__))
print('Matplotlib: {:}'.format(matplotlib.__version__))
print('')

def test(data, s=3):
  XT = matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction']
  matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'in'
  YT = matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction']
  matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'in'

  fig = plt.figure(None)
  grid = matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec(1, 1)
  grid.update(wspace=0, hspace=0)

  ax = plt.subplot(grid[0])
  ax.scatter(*data, c='k', marker='.', s=s)

  ax.set_xlim(data[0,:].min(), data[0,:].max())
  ax.set_ylim(6,13)

  ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(4))
  ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
  ax.invert_yaxis() # invert y axis because magnitudes suck

  ax.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='x', scilimits=(-3,4))
  ax.xaxis.tick_top()
  ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('both')
  ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=-10, labelsize=6)

  for i, tick in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()):
    print("{:}: {:}".format(i, tick.get_loc()))

  matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = XT
  matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = YT

  plt.savefig('test.png')
  plt.close()

  return None

_data = np.array([
                  [2017.33030847, 8.219],
                  [2017.33040156, 8.7],
                  [2017.33042138, 8.66],
                  [2017.33042305, 8.522],
                  [2017.33042486, 8.552],
                  [2017.33042669, 8.533],
                  [2017.33193969, 8.5],
                  [2017.33198084, 8.3],
                  [2017.33237782, 8.2],
                  [2017.33304624, 8.3],
                  [2017.33315704, 8.674],
                  [2017.33315869, 8.533],
                  [2017.33316049, 8.556],
                  [2017.33316233, 8.564],
                  [2017.33471869, 8.3],
                  [2017.33514031, 8.3],
                  [2017.33526788, 8.553],
                  [2017.335884, 8.803],
                  [2017.33588591, 8.643],
                  [2017.33588805, 8.459],
                  [2017.33589005, 8.623],
                  [2017.3372728, 8.6],
                  [2017.33731083, 8.5],
                  [2017.33740178, 8.3],
                  [2017.33763492, 8.642],
                  [2017.33772912, 8.4],
                  [2017.33863773, 8.85],
                  [2017.33863945, 8.725],
                  [2017.33864134, 8.618],
                  [2017.33864312, 8.722],
                  [2017.34001065, 8.6],
                  [2017.34036185, 8.587],
                  [2017.34044986, 8.5],
                  [2017.34134218, 8.901],
                  [2017.34134385, 8.737],
                  [2017.34134565, 8.701],
                  [2017.34134749, 8.762],
                  [2017.34135105, 8.7],
                  [2017.34148646, 8.676],
                  [2017.34293224, 8.4],
                  [2017.3430299, 8.7],
                  [2017.34309193, 8.746],
                  [2017.34406418, 8.8],
                  [2017.34407559, 8.6],
                  [2017.34409213, 9.046],
                  [2017.3440938, 8.909],
                  [2017.34409566, 8.842],
                  [2017.34409758, 8.945],
                  [2017.34413369, 8.829],
                  [2017.34413481, 8.823],
                  [2017.34545402, 8.9],
                  [2017.3455586, 8.65],
                  [2017.34565366, 8.7],
                  [2017.3459939, 8.965],
                  [2017.3466423, 9.0],
                  [2017.3485529, 9.171],
                  [2017.34927556, 9.2],
                  [2017.35129176, 9.479],
                  [2017.35140589, 9.43],
                  [2017.35207803, 9.5],
                  [2017.35504756, 10.224],
                  [2017.35504917, 10.049],
                  [2017.35505101, 9.934],
                  [2017.3550529, 9.888],
                  [2017.35688835, 10.6],
                  [2017.35778546, 10.758],
                  [2017.3577871, 10.588],
                  [2017.35778899, 10.438],
                  [2017.35779083, 10.324],
                  [2017.35909574, 10.6],
                  [2017.36045892, 11.077],
                  [2017.36046363, 10.901],
                  [2017.36046831, 10.646],
                  [2017.36047302, 10.313],
                  [2017.36246264, 11.292],
                  [2017.36304093, 11.4],
                  [2017.36319206, 11.627],
                  [2017.3631968, 11.312],
                  [2017.36320159, 10.973],
                  [2017.36320632, 10.593],
                  [2017.36324624, 11.2],
                  [2017.36512412, 11.426],
                  [2017.36594136, 12.087],
                  [2017.36594612, 11.668],
                  [2017.36595083, 11.246],
                  [2017.36595556, 10.747],
                  [2017.36616392, 11.574],
                  [2017.36616507, 11.593],
                  [2017.36744238, 11.7],
                  [2017.36749076, 11.7],
                  [2017.36814631, 11.755],
                  [2017.36874286, 11.9],
                  [2017.37039888, 11.9],
                  [2017.3728553, 12.1],
                  [2017.373535, 11.963],
                  [2017.3739885, 11.7],
                  [2017.37540315, 11.8],
                  [2017.37572819, 11.7],
                  [2017.3781191, 11.8],
                  [2017.37844131, 11.8],
                 ]).T

test(_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that you can get the tick location without drawing the figure with

```
ax.get_xticks()
```

which returns an array of the x tick location. These are indexex in the same order as

```
ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
```

so to use the x tick location to do something usfull with the tick/labels one can do the following:

```
xticks = ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
xlocs = ax.get_xticks()
for i, x in enumerate(xlocs):
    tick = xticks[i]
    if some_condition(x): # put your condition here
        do_stuff_to(tick) # act on tick here
```

Answer (score 1):

The location of the ticks is only determined at draw time.

Therefore, in order to have access to the actual positions, you need to draw the figure first. This can be done via

```
fig.canvas.draw()
```

and would result in the actual positions printed

```
0: 0
1: 2017.34
2: 2017.35
3: 2017.36
4: 2017.37
5: 0
```